# Sort PHP - 2 columns with common subheaders

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

My code does the two columns, like this:

neighborhood 1
restaurant 1

neighborhood 1
restaurant 2

neighborhood 1
restaurant 3

I WANT:

neighborhood 1
restaurant 1
restaurant 2
restaurant 3

---

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT ID,RName,NHood FROM Restaurants ORDER BY NHood ASC, TRIM(LEADING 'The ' FROM RName) ASC",$connect);
$numRows = mysql_num_rows($result);
$middleIndex = (int)(($numRows+1) / 2);

$names = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $names[] = $row['RName'];
    $id[] = $row['ID'];
    $hood[] = $row['NHood'];
}

// print the left column
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td width=60%>";
echo "<div id=\"left\">\n";
for($i = 0; $i < $middleIndex; $i++) {
    echo $hood[$i];
    echo "<p><a href=\"Restaurant.php?ID=".$id[$i]."\">$names[$i]</a></p>\n";
}
echo "</div>\n";
echo "</td>";

// print the right column
echo "<td>";
echo "<div id=\"right\">\n";
for($i = $middleIndex; $i < $numRows; $i++) {
    echo $hood[$i];
        echo "<p><a href=\"Restaurant.php?ID=".$id[$i]."\">$names[$i]</a></p>\n";
}
echo "</div>\n";  
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: As usual, FYI: the `mysql_*` function are deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. `PDO` is the new way to go.

Comment: I think you need to add a `GROUP BY NHood` in your MySQL Query. Your result set would include all the NHood results in Order Ascending. Adding Group By would group all the results that have the same NHood. Do you have some example result sets?

Comment: `mysql_num_rows` returns an INT, so there is no need to cast the result of a mathematical function involving this number to an int: `$middleIndex = (int)(($numRows+1) / 2);`

Comment: Thank you for all the comments...I've attempted the GROUP BY still gives me the same results (which I have updated above)....I'm not having a problem with the columns....it's getting more than one restaurant to list under the NHOod.....THanks.  Kim

Answer (score 1):

Here's the logic you want (pseduocode):

```
SELECT
    ID,
    RName,
    NHood
FROM
    Restaurants
ORDER BY
    NHood ASC, RName ASC
```

This should return a list of results ordered first by the neighborhood, then by restaurant name.

Next, you'll process those results line-by-line to create a nested array with the data structure you want for your view:

```
$neighborhoods = array();

foreach($result as $row)
{
    // Add each restaurant to a list named for the current neighborhood
    $neighborhoods[$row['NHood']][] = $row['RName'];
}
```

This will produce a data structure like this:

```
$neighborhoods = array(
    'neighborhood1' => array(
        'restaurant1',
        'restaurant2',
        'restaurant3',
    ),
    'neighborhood2' => array(
        'restaurant1',
        'restaurant2',
    ),
)
```

Which you will then use by doing this:

```
foreach($neighborhoods as $neighborhood => $restaurants)
{
    echo $neighborhood;
    foreach($restaurants as $restaurant)
    {
        echo $restaurant;
    }
}
```

If your list is really large and you're worried about memory the implementation is a bit different but the logic is the same. This technique is faster but it's a bit harder to read and maintain because presentation and data layer logic are all mixed together:

```
$currentNH = null;

while($row = fetch_row($results))
{
    // Detect when the neighborhood changes
    if($currentNH != $row['NHood']) {
        echo $row['NHood'];
    }

    echo $row['RName'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much cbednarski.  this logic makes sense....though try as I might, I'm still missing something...I still need to get it in two columns...and somewhere I just have too much code going on?  I keep getting an error for the foreach? Am I mixing "old school" with PDO (per JMAx?)  Thank you =)

Comment: Not sure which `foreach` you're referring to since there are three of them, but if you're using pdo you're either going to do use `foreach($results->fetchAll() as $row)` or `while($row = $result->fetch())`. Look at the docs for [`PDOStatement::fetch*()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php) to see which one you need.